# How to change the page layout with memoir?

Tags: margins, memoir

On the question [How to do the memoir headings fix but not have my text going over the page bottom margins?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387257/how-to-do-the-memoir-headings-fix-but-not-have-my-text-going-over-the-page-botto) was said by @daleif:

> Also use the memoir interface to change the layout instead of manipulating individual lengths

So, how would I use the *memoir interface* to set the `\setlength{\headheight}{14.0pt}`?

Also, for changing the page layout I am using this:

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{1.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2cm}{1.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout%
```

Would this be correct with the *memoir interface* mentioned for changing the layout?

---

Related:

1. [Specific margin size in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/specific-margin-size-in-memoir)
2. [Trying to understand Memoir page layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157294/trying-to-understand-memoir-page-layout)
3. [Memoir Page Layout doesn't work as expected: Text shifted right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/memoir-page-layout-doesnt-work-as-expected-text-shifted-right)

Comment: Have you checked the memoir documentation?

Comment: `\setheadfoot{<headheight>}{<hfootskip>}`

Comment: Out of interest, why are you putting the *related links* into your questions?

Comment: @Johannes_B I think to show that he has done research. In addition, if someone searches in the future for a similar problem, then they get a wider range of related answers.

Comment: @Johannes_B as already said, but also I can save them together so when I need them again they are by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in section 2.5 of the `memoir` manual *Headers , Footers and Marginal Notes* you can do that by setting

```
\setheadfoot{14pt}{<hfootskip>}
```

Be advised of the recommendation

> It is usual to set the `\headheight` to at least the value of the `\baselineskip` of the normal body font.

Comment: Thanks! I was reading section `2.4` while writing this question. Now I scrolled a little and got on section `2.5`.  But it is saying `The \setheadfoot macro sets the \headheight parameter to the value hheadheighti and the \footskip`. But on the fix [Memoir : Warnings “The material used in the headers is too large” w/ accented titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310493) they do not set the `\footskip`. How can I keep its value while using `\setheadfoot{14pt}{<hfootskip>}`?

Comment: try only `\setheadfoot{14pt}{}`. does it compile, or it ends in errors?

Comment: Using `\setheadfoot{14pt}{}` it throw these errors `Missing number, treated as zero. Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)`, but doing `\setheadfoot{14.0pt}{\footskip}` seems to not throw error or warnings. Would `\setheadfoot{14.0pt}{\footskip}` be correct?

Comment: yes, you can also use the `\checkandfixthelayout` to make sure everything is ok (see the manual for its usage)